# Change default row background color on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that when a row is tapped a `UIView` pops up, everything is working fine but what I want is to be able to change the background color of the row when it's tapped to other color than the default gray. The standard behavior which is how I have it right now, behaves as follow, when I tap the row it changes the background color to gray and when I dismiss the popup `UIView` the background color changes back to the default white.

What I want is to be able to change the background color to blue when a row is tapped and changed it back to white when the UIView is dismissed.

I tried the following, which changes the color when the row is tapped but it doesn't change it back to white when the popup UIView is dismissed. In other words, it leaves the tapped rows with a blue background

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    /// Change color of the selected row
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

How can I change the background of a cell when it's tapped and change it back to the default white when the popup UIView is dismissed?

FYI - I tried the `didDeselectRowAt` but it's never called.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`didDeselectRowAt` is called when you tap another cell while the current is selected , you need to check `viewDidAppear` if the dismiss calles it or use a delegate otherwise and inside it add this code

```
tableView.visibleCells.forEach { 
  $0.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: @ Sh_Khan - So, if `didDeselectRowAt ` is called when you tap another cell while the current is selected why is that I it never gets called, I added your code inside the `didDeselectRowAt` and that code never gets called.  If I keep tapping cells it just make all rows blue. I also tried adding `let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue` and again, it never gets called.  Where should I be calling your code from?

Answer (score 1):

try this you have to set selection style to none when you return cell **cell.selectionStyle = .none**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Your identifier", for: indexPath)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
 }
```

Comment: Adding `cell.selectionStyle = .none` does nothing.